# Load numeric array from text file in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, file

I'm using a Swift function that successfully loads data from a text file into an `Double` array, but it is slow. Is there a way to load numeric data directly without using the `String` initializer that may be faster? Or any other suggestions to speed this up?

```
func arrayFromContentsOfFileWithPath(path: String) -> [Double]? {
    do {
        let content = try String(contentsOfFile:path, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        let stringArray = content.componentsSeparatedByString("\n").map{
            $0.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet())
        }
        return stringArray.map{Double($0)}.flatMap{$0}
    } catch _ as NSError {
        return nil
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**
To quantify things a  bit, the data file is 10000 samples and the load time is 0.183 s for a single load (according to a `measureBlock` in my unit tests). In comparison, MATLAB loads the file in 0.033 s. Here are the first few samples of the data:

```
   8.1472369e-01
   9.0579194e-01
   1.2698682e-01
   9.1337586e-01
   6.3235925e-01
   9.7540405e-02
   2.7849822e-01
   5.4688152e-01
   9.5750684e-01
   9.6488854e-01
```

**UPDATE:** 
Following @appzYourLife's advice to combine the mappings (I used `.flatMap{Double($0)}`) and to use a Release build, the load time is now 0.119 s. Much better, but still about 4x the time of MATLAB, which was very unexpected.

Comment: Why do you think the String initializer is what's slow?

Comment: @matt Not much else there; what else do you think might be causing it?

Comment: @Rogare: What is the size of the input file, the time of execution and the hardware you are using?

Comment: I don't think anything. I would use Instruments and _see_. Also please show your actual input file content if you want real help.

Comment: @appzYourLife Thanks for the comment, please see new edits

Comment: @Rogare: just a tiny optimization, there is no need to call both `map` and then `flatMap`: you can replace this `return stringArray.map{Double($0)}.flatMap{$0}` with this `stringArray.flatMap(Double.init)`

Comment: @appzYourLife Thanks! That change does help, though as you predicted it's a minor one (0.183 -> 0.177 s).

Comment: @Rogare: Next, are you using a `Debug` build or a `Release` one?

Comment: @appzYourLife It's running in my unit tests, so I believe it's the Debug build. (TBH, a little fuzzy on that.)

Comment: @Rogare: this could be the reason. A release build is much more optimized and it should be noticeably faster.

Comment: @appzYourLife Yup, confirmed I was on a Debug build. Changing to release helped, but still about 4X the MATLAB load time.

Comment: @Rogare: is this an iOS app you are running into the simulator?

Comment: @appzYourLife Nope, it's an OS X framework.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can read data quite fast with `NSScanner()`. The `scanDouble()`
method skips leading whitespace, so no intermediate strings or arrays
are needed:

```
func arrayFromContentsOfFileWithPath(path: String) -> [Double]? {
    do {
        let content = try String(contentsOfFile:path, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        let scanner = NSScanner(string: content)
        var doubleArray = [Double]()
        var value = 0.0
        while scanner.scanDouble(&value) {
            doubleArray.append(value)
        }
        return doubleArray
    } catch _ as NSError {
        return nil
    }
}
```

In my test, reading 10,000 samples in Release configuration is
done in 0.0034 seconds, compared to 0.077 seconds with your code,
that is an improvement of more than factor 20.

Update for **Swift 3:**

```
func arrayFromContentsOfFileWithPath(path: String) -> [Double]? {
    guard let content = try? String(contentsOfFile:path, encoding: .utf8) else {
        return nil
    }
    let scanner = Scanner(string: content)
    var doubleArray = [Double]()
    var value = 0.0
    while scanner.scanDouble(&value) {
        doubleArray.append(value)
    }
    return doubleArray
}
```

Comment: Yup, I'm seeing 180 ms -> 9 ms on my end as well, so a 20x improvement. Fantastic, thanks! Seems like all that mapping was the bottleneck.